# read numbers from huge text file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to read a pretty big text file in TypeScript / nodejs.
this is how I currently do this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const stream = createReadStream(`${folder}/${file}`)
                stream.on('error', function(error) {
                    const msg = `error: ${error.message}`
                    console.log(msg)
                    reject(msg)
                })
                stream.on('data', chunk => {
                    //write to coordinates
                        chunk
                        .toString()
                        .split('\n')
                        .map((line: string) => line.split(/[,\s;]+/)) // Accept " ", "," and ";" as delimiter
                        .map((line: string[]) => {
                        
                            const point = [+line[0], +line[1], +line[2]]
                            
                            // console.log(point, bbox, bboxSize)
                            if (isInsideBoundingBox(point, bbox, bboxSize)) {
                                coordinatesList.push({
                                    x: point[0],
                                    y: point[1],
                                    z: point[2],
                                })
                            }
                        })
                })
                stream.on('close', () => {
                    resolve('')
                })
            })
```

it does work. the file I am reading is around 40.000 lines long and consists of lines like that:

```
401438.00 5650223.00 344.68
401439.00 5650223.00 344.78
401440.00 5650223.00 344.87
401441.00 5650223.00 344.93
401442.00 5650223.00 345.00
401443.00 5650223.00 345.08
```

so what I am doing is, parse all the coordinates into an array of `{x:number,y:nunmber,z:number}[]`

BUT from time to time it does not recognize the values correctly and returns a "null". I just cannot find out why. The Text file I am reading is perfectly fine. sometimes in this line for example it returns x: null > 401440.00 5650223.00 344.87 witch should be 344.87.

the only thing I can think of is that there is something dodgy with my use of chunks. so I am thinking its not big enough and makes another chunk, and forgets some bits and pieces of the read text file? I really don't have any clue how I can solve this issue.

any idea how I would find the error would be just awesome!

Thank you very much!

Comment: 40k lines is not all that big, especially as each line only appears to be about 30 bytes. Have you considered simply reading the whole file, splitting on newline, then processing each line? As it stands, you're probably getting some portion of a line at the end of a chunk, I'd guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm assumes that every chunk received by the `data` event listener consists of complete lines, which is not necessarily the case. You can split a stream into lines with [`readline.createInterface`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/readline.html#readlinecreateinterfaceoptions):

```js
var coordinatesList = [];
readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(`${folder}/${file}`),
  crlfDelay: Infinity
})
.on('line', function(line) {
  line.split(/[,\s;]+/) // Accept " ", "," and ";" as delimiter
    .map((line) => {
      const point = [+line[0], +line[1], +line[2]]
      if (isInsideBoundingBox(point, bbox, bboxSize)) {
        coordinatesList.push({
          x: point[0],
          y: point[1],
          z: point[2],
        })
      }
    })
})
.on('close', () => {
  console.log(coordinatesList);
});
```

Comment: hey, that looks very promising! is there any difference on how .on("close"... works? i can console log points from each line, but it does not push anything to my coordinates array. is the file closed before anything is done?

Comment: The `close` event comes after all `line` events. It works for me, see my edited answer.